# Vista hibernate not working/not an option

Tags: windows-vista, hibernate

I can't put my laptop into hibernation anymore.

The story goes like this:

had an issue with the space on the C: drive, and as a solution I did the following:
 - disk cleanup (all options selected, including delete hibernate file).
 - removed the system restore from all the drives.

After this the hibernate option is not displayed any more (probably because the hibernate file was deleted).

How can I enable the hibernate on my Vista system?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/920730) microsoft kb article on enabling/disabling hibernation:

To make hibernation available, follow these steps:

1. Click Start, and then type cmd in the Start Search box.
2. In the search results list, right-click Command Prompt, and then click Run as        Administrator.
3. When you are prompted by User Account Control, click Continue.
4. At the command prompt, type powercfg.exe /hibernate on, and then press ENTER.
5. Type exit, and then press ENTER to close the Command Prompt window.

Answer (score 1):

Just type **'powercfg -h on**' in a shell with adminitrator rights. Disk cleanup certainly removed the hiberfil.sys file.

Comment: To run a shell with admin rights, create a bat file that contains the following: 'start cmd' (except the ' chars ), in win right click and select run as administrator...